# increase upload efficiency for cassandra

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, cassandra, cql3, cqlsh

I am uploading data from .csv files into Cassandra cluster deployed in Amazon EC2 using COPY command from EBS volume attached to it. I noticed that the Cassandra upload time increases very badly, with increase in size of the .csv file.

Is there a way in which I can tune the settings to increase the load rate for cassandra.. ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a [real bulk loader](http://www.datastax.com/documentation/cassandra/1.2/cassandra/tools/toolsBulkloader_t.html).  COPY is not appropriate for millions of records.

Comment: I split my large file into files each having 2 million records. I am trying to upload them simultaneously from 2 Cassandra nodes. Although not very efficient, do you foresee any other issues in this approach..? I was facing issues with SSTableLoader as I am uploading from a .csv export of mysql database. Hence I resorted to COPY as it was less complex..